# alias shell variable dereference

Tags: shell, alias, dereference, tcsh

I move about a lot in paths, and trying to use an alias set to minimize typing:

```
alias restore       'set restore=\!*; cd \$${restore}'
alias save          'setenv \!* `pwd`'
```

I'm using tcsh; the save works but the restore fails:

```
2% save x
2% cd
2% restore x
$x: No such file or directory.
```

I inspect the var (x) and it's fine so I'm not dereferencing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
alias restore ' cd ` echo $\!* ` '
```

---

Your original attempt can be better written as:

```
alias restore ' cd \$\!* '
```

This (and your original one) doesn't work because variable expansion needs to happen first, and in this case there is no variable expansion, because `$` is escaped.  After `!*` is expanded, there isn't another variable expansion happening.

In my proposed solution I avoid escaping `$` by running a `echo` in a sub-shell, so it works fine.

---

Just to make sure, you are aware of `pushd` and `popd`, right? For most users, those are useful and powerful enough, though I can certainly see the value in your aliases here.

Comment: Ah, I have some historical baggage that push/pop were more about shells (ptycon to be exact from a by-gone era). ;-)  I wouldn't trump those with push/pop so save/restore;  I'm setting on this, thanks:

        alias restore       'cd `echo $\!*`; pwd'